# Extending a base class to a derived class

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

We have two classes BasicRace & AdvancedRace.
AdvancedRace inherits from BasicRace

I have a BasicRace but i want to 'convert' it to the advanced class.

See code below as a example:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim bRace As New BasicRace With {.CourseID = 1, .MeetingDate = "2013-05-01", .RaceNumber = 1}
        Dim aRace As New AdvancedRace

        ' Upgrade bRace to AdvancedRace???????
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class BasicRace
    Public Property MeetingDate As Date
    Public Property CourseID As Integer
    Public Property RaceNumber As Integer
End Class

Public Class AdvancedRace
    Inherits BasicRace
    Public Property RaceTitle As String
End Class
```

Any help would be great - I'm starting to think it can not be done unless i write a function to convert a basicRace to AdvancedRace going through each property one  by one?

Comment: You could write a constructor of Advanced race that took a argument of basic race, and do it that way.

Comment: How would i pass the basicRace to the Base of the AdvancedClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "convert" from a base class to a subclass as such (you can't change the type of an existing object), but you can create  new instance of the subclass that copies the properties from your base class.

Typical ways of implementing this for your classes might be:

- a constructor in `AdvancedRace` that takes a `BasicRace` parameter and copies properties from it
- a static method in `AdvancedRace` that takes a `BasicRace` parameter, creates the new object with copied properties, and then returns it

It's worth noting that this will result in two completely separate objects (one of each type) that aren't linked at all - changes in your `AdvancedRace` object won't be reflected in the `BasicRace` or vice-versa.

Comment: I’m starting to get the impression there is no way round this,
I’m going to have to write and maintain some code to convert from BasicRace to AdvancedRace

Comment: Yes, you'll definitely need something of that form.