# class inheritance and casting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I want to extend a the basic user class of my website to add staff features for the different groups. Is this possible?

For example:

UserWebsite

UserStaffProgrammer

UserStaffSales

Then in the UserWebsite I have the function GetByUserId. It fetches from the database and loads all their attributes.

`Public Shared Function GetByUserId(ByVal userId As Integer) As UserWebsite`

Staff users use the same reg process like a website users but we also have more features not available to normal website users. In the staff classes, I want to add features like gitUserName or sales team manager.

```
Public Class UserStaffProgrammer 

Inherits UserWebsite

    Public Overloads Function GetByUserId(ByVal staffId As Integer) As UserStaffProgrammer
        Dim toReturn As UserStaffProgrammer = UserWebsite.GetByUserId(staffId)
        toReturn.loadStaffFeatures()
        Return toReturn
    End Function
End Class
```

I get a cast error trying to do this.

> Unable to cast object of type 'UserWebsite' to type
>   'UserStaffProgrammer'

. Is what I'm trying to do possible in vb.net?

Comment: Learn about inheritance and encapsulation as implemented in VB.

Comment: or alternately, what would be the ideal way to add features for a staff user while getting features from basic UserWebsite?

Comment: Unrelated, but that function should not be overloaded (infact it should not even be possible to do so). It should be [**shadowed**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354321/extending-a-base-class-to-a-derived-class